# neo4j rest API resultDataContents:graph does not really returns one graph?

Tags: neo4j

To make yet another d3 viewer, I'd like to get a graph out from a rest query.

In my understanding, stating 'resultDataContent':['graph'] would return a graph. Instead, it return a list of subgraphs and I need therefore to collect and distinct the nodes. Is there a way to get the full sub graph simply?

For example, I put these 4 nodes

```
CREATE (a:Person {name:'a'})
CREATE (b:Person {name:'b'})
CREATE (c:Person {name:'c'})
CREATE (d:Person {name:'d'})
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
CREATE (a)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
CREATE (b)-[:KNOWS]->(c)
CREATE (c)-[:KNOWS]->(d)
```

But calling a POST query with the following query will return 2 results.data, each of them with a "graph", consisting of 2 nodes and a links?

```
{"statements":[
    {
    "statement":"MATCH (p:Person {name:{pName}})-[l:KNOWS]-(q:Person) RETURN p,l,q",
    "parameters":{"pName":"a"},
    "resultDataContents":["graph"]
    }
]}
```

Is there a way to return the one subgraph, without the need to reassemble the results?

Thanks for the help,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that the same person will be returned twice by your query. Change the return statement to:

```
RETURN collect(distinct(p)),collect(l),collect(distinct(q))
```

That will give you the following response:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "collect(distinct(p))",
        "collect(l)",
        "collect(distinct(q))"
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "graph": {
            "nodes": [
              {
                "id": "1849644",
                "labels": [
                  "Person"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "name": "b"
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "1849645",
                "labels": [
                  "Person"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "name": "c"
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "1849643",
                "labels": [
                  "Person"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "name": "a"
                }
              }
            ],
            "relationships": [
              {
                "id": "4052753",
                "type": "KNOWS",
                "startNode": "1849643",
                "endNode": "1849644",
                "properties": {}
              },
              {
                "id": "4052754",
                "type": "KNOWS",
                "startNode": "1849643",
                "endNode": "1849645",
                "properties": {}
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "errors": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst working on something similar (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067792/neo4j-cypher-gui) I've run into the same problem. The documentation: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html is very light on the subject